# How can I show photos in popup from a ByteA (postgis) in QGIS (or Google Earth/map)

Tags: qgis, postgis, google-maps, google-earth

I currently have a postgis database with a table containing point geometry of fire Hydrant. This table contains a raster_blob field which contains the Fire hydrant picture taken by field workers.  Would there be a way to read the picture from the PostGIS ByteArray so it can be shown in a label or pop-up using QGIS (or Google Earth/map)?

Comment: This isn't really a GIS question. Usually people put a little web service in front of their database, getpicture.php?id=12345 or something, that reads the record in question, sets the Content-Type of the response to image/png and streams the blob, so that a web component will magically display it.